# Getting syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting ']'

Tags: php, database

For my php function. 
i have these codes

```
DB::table('trades')->where('id', $trade->id)
                            ->update(['status' => 'done',
                                  'accepted_trade_message_id' => $message->id,
                                  'updated_at' => date("Y-m-d h:i:s")]);
```

But i getting these error while preview in website

```
FatalErrorException in PageController.php line 2644: syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting ']'
```

I can't figure out why i already without the ',' but still the same?

Thanks

Comment: What line is 2644?  Also do a `var_export()` of `$trade->id` and `$message->id`.

Answer (score 0):

Answer figured out by previous function of ',' . 
Thanks